# Duplicate labels in ArcGIS Server REST map service OpenLayers 5

Tags: arcgis-server, openlayers, map-service, plss

I'm trying to export PLSS grid from ArcGIS map server and I have a duplicate labels in PLSS map service. Using OpenLayers 5
[image]
My code

```
    mapPLSSTownshipLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
    source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
        url: 'https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastral/BLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI/MapServer/export?dynamicLayers=[{"id":1,"source":{"type":"mapLayer","mapLayerId":1},"minScale":4000000.000000047,"maxScale":0,"drawingInfo":{"renderer":{"type":"simple","symbol":{"type":"esriSFS","color":[0,255,0,0],"outline":{"type":"esriSLS","color":[38,38,38,255],"width":2}}},"labelingInfo":[{"labelPlacement":"esriServerPolygonPlacementAlwaysHorizontal","labelExpression":"[TWNSHPLAB]","minScale":550000,"maxScale":0,"symbol":{"type":"esriTS","color":[0,0,0,255],"haloColor":[255,255,255,255],"haloSize":2,"font":{"family":"Arial","size":13}}}]}}]&TRANSPARENT=true&SIZE=700%2C700',
        params: {
            'DPI':210,
            'FORMAT':'PNG24'
        },
        ratio: 1
    }),
    maxResolution: 300
});
```

I tried change image size but my params seems overwriting by default
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: OpenLayers will override tile size to match the tile size of its tile grid (the default is 256).  When using a zoom factor of two set `tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({tileSize: 512})` or `tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({tileSize: 1024})` as an option in the source.

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
   tileSize: [2500, 2500]
})
```

into my source and no more duplicate labels.

```
mapPLSSTownshipLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
    source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
    url: 'https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastral/BLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI/MapServer/export?dynamicLayers=[{"id":1,"source":{"type":"mapLayer","mapLayerId":1},"minScale":4000000.000000047,"maxScale":0,"drawingInfo":{"renderer":{"type":"simple","symbol":{"type":"esriSFS","color":[0,255,0,0],"outline":{"type":"esriSLS","color":[38,38,38,255],"width":2}}},"labelingInfo":[{"labelPlacement":"esriServerPolygonPlacementAlwaysHorizontal","labelExpression":"[TWNSHPLAB]","minScale":1050000,"maxScale":0,"symbol":{"type":"esriTS","color":[0,0,0,255],"haloColor":[255,255,255,255],"haloSize":2,"font":{"family":"Arial","size":5}}}]}}]&TRANSPARENT=true&SIZE=1000%2C1000',
    params: {
       'DPI':95,
       'FORMAT':'PNG24'
    },
    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
        tileSize: [2500, 2500]
    }),
    maxResolution: 300
});
```

Thank you [Mike](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/102658/mike).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with "singleTile" as true in the layer options.  For dynamic ArcServer layers, OL was requesting multiple (dynamic) tiles so it was making multiple labels.

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest( "ArcGIS Server Layer","http://localhost/arcgis/rest/services/AmountofTaxesDue/MapServer/export", 
            {layers: "show:0,2"},
            {  "singleTile": true}
        );
```